# Multiple Seller with own admin access

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore

I was wondering whether the following can be achieved with magento:

A client submits an order for a product and selects a specific physical store location to pickup his product. That order is  then sent to that store. The seller at that store has restricted access to the admin panel where he can only manage orders relating to his store only. There are several stores and all have similar functionality. In a way a physical store has an own profile on the online store. There is also a super admin that controls everything. So instead of having 5 different online stores for each store, each store will just have individual access to the online store and manage the orders relating to their stores.

Please note that this is not "multi-vendor" as products across all stores are the same. In other words it is just one online store with multiple outlets.

Answer (score 1):

One of the Enterprise Edition features is store based admin access.
One possible setup would be to set up each physical store with a matching Magento store view.

For the community edition there might also be extensions offering that, but I personally don't know any.

Answer (score 1):

I **highly** recommend [looking into Unirgy uDropship](http://www.unirgy.com//products/udropship/) for this, as this is what the product does. It may be possible to locked down the admin enough (at least with Enterprise Edition, as Vinai points out) that you have **fairly insulated access** per-store, but I wouldn't trust installed *3rd party modules* to have the same sort of insulation -- and that sort of risk is enough for me to distrust this as a real solution.

[Unirgy](http://www.unirgy.com) is a company that provides marketplace and dropshipping solutions that are purpose-built **for this business model**. Believe me, this is more common than you might have thought.

They're expensive modules, to be sure, but orders of magnitude less expensive than Enterprise Edition on it's own. **I am not endorsed by Unirgy** - I'm just a huge fan of their products.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unirgy sounds like the solution, I'll have to consider the pricing.